# Restrict a Batch user access from SQL Assistant

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

Could you please guide me how to restrict a Batch user access only from SQL Assistant. I am using Teradata Version 17. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Umair

Restrict a Batch user access only from SQL Assistant

Comment: Unclear exactly what you are asking. Workload Management "filter" rule can check Username and Application (or IP address) and reject matching queries. Teradata database can also restrict connections based on combination of Username and IP.

Comment: A typical case would be  "Reject any query from this list of usernames unless source is one of these specific servers" which can be done using a filter rule with "include" classification on username and "exclude" on client IP.  It's also possible (though less useful) to set a filter rule that allows a given username to submit queries only via SQL Assistant (or alternatively, reject SQL Assistant but allow use of any tool other than SQL Assistant).

Answer (score 0):

This could be your restriction filter:

```
select * from Dbc.sessionInfo 
where 
LogonSource like '% SQLA %'
```